# Cannot get the reverse URL from 3rd party packages in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am aware of Django's reverse function:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
reverse('my_view_name')
```

However, if I want to get the URL using reverse from a 3rd part package I get a `NoReverseMatch`.

For example, take the package [oauth2_provider](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/tree/master/oauth2_provider) where I want to get the token URL it provides.

my include urls.py...

```
url(r'^api/', include('oauth2_provider.urls', namespace='oauth2_provider')),
```

Then I do `reverse('token')` and get

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'token' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

why?

looking inside the package URL the name is `token` [here](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/urls.py#L10)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace when reversing the url:

```
reverse('oauth2_provider:token')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the info. I was looking for reference to this in the Django docs, did I just miss it?

Comment: It's a bit hidden away in the [part about namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls).